# Sort/Alphabetzing Columns in Dataframes (Pandas)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, alphabetical-sort

I'm having trouble alphabetizing the names in the first and second column of a dataframe.

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
          Boys       Females
Rank                        
1         Michael   Jennifer
2     Christopher    Jessica
3         Matthew     Amanda
4           Jason      Sarah
5           David    Melissa
6          Joshua        Amy
7           James     Nicole
8            John  Stephanie
9          Robert  Elizabeth
10         Daniel    Heather
11         Joseph   Michelle
12         Justin    Rebecca
13           Ryan   Kimberly
14          Brian    Tiffany
```

And I want it look like this: (The Boys and Females name are in alphabetical order)

```
 Rank     Boys                 Rank    Females
 14       Brian                  3        Amanda
  2       Christopher            6        Amy
 10       Daniel                 9        Elizabeth
  5       David                 10        Heather
  7       James                  1        Jennifer
```

I've played around with sort and sort_value but the columns are not changing. Here is my original code

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_html("file:///C:/Python27/babyname999.html")

df2 =df[0]  # creating a data frame from the above list of dateframes

df2.rename(columns = {'0': 'Rank', '1': 'Boys', '2': 'Females'}, inplace = True)
del df2['Unnamed: 0']

#renaming columns of dataframe


df2.set_index('Rank', inplace = True)  #setting index of dataframe to 'Rank'
```

I've played around with sort and sort_value but the columns are not changing. I got no where. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your desired data set, because it's not clear what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. For the Boys column I would like to see Brian first and then have the list continue in an alphabetical fashion ending with Robert.For the the females side I would like Amy to be on top and the have the list continue in an alphabetical fashion. I would like to have both the Boys and Females in alphabetical order simultaneously. 

As for the rank, I would like rank to follow the name. So even though after the sort, Michael will be somewhere in the middle of the list, he would still retain Rank "1."

Comment: So I would need to have another rank column for the female alphabetical version as well, which I just realized. 
Does it make sense now? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you simply [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39429614/edit) your desired sorted DF, because it's still not clear to me?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with sorting different columns of a dataframe independently is that pandas will just use the index of each independently sorted column and realign them, thus destroying your sorting efforts.  You must instead, sort and return the values of the resulting sorted series... enough talk, an example will explain much more.

Assume `df` is your example dataframe.  Then

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values)
```

[image]

---

To get something close to what you asked for

```
lst = [df[c].sort_values().reset_index(name='Name') for c in df]
keys = df.columns
pd.concat(lst, axis=1, keys=keys)
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. I will take a look at your code and see if I have any further questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's working example of sorting.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_file = StringIO(u"""Rank       Boys       Females
1         Michael   Jennifer
2     Christopher    Jessica
3         Matthew     Amanda
4           Jason      Sarah
5           David    Melissa
6          Joshua        Amy
7           James     Nicole
8            John  Stephanie
9          Robert  Elizabeth
10         Daniel    Heather
11         Joseph   Michelle
12         Justin    Rebecca
13           Ryan   Kimberly
14          Brian    Tiffany""")

df = pd.read_table(data_file, delim_whitespace=True)

boys = df[['Rank','Boys']].sort_values(['Boys']).rename(columns={'Rank': 'Rank_boys'})
females = df[['Rank','Females']].sort_values(['Females']).rename(columns={'Rank': 'Rank_females'})
result = pd.concat([boys.reset_index(drop=True), females.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

And result would be:

```
Rank_boys Boys Rank_females Females
0   14  Brian   3   Amanda
1   2   Christopher 6   Amy
2   10  Daniel  9   Elizabeth
3   5   David   10  Heather
4   7   James   1   Jennifer
5   4   Jason   2   Jessica
6   8   John    13  Kimberly
7   11  Joseph  5   Melissa
8   6   Joshua  11  Michelle
9   12  Justin  7   Nicole
10  3   Matthew 12  Rebecca
11  1   Michael 4   Sarah
12  9   Robert  8   Stephanie
13  13  Ryan    14  Tiffany
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking to do for the Boys and Females column simultaneously.

I will look at your code and see if I have any questions. 
Thanks.

Comment: After  seeing your code it seems I would need to  create another rank column for the females as well. I'm not familiar with the StringIO module so I will have to read up on it.

Comment: StringIO is just there to create a data frame from the data sample in your question.

Comment: ok I have edited the answer and I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks this works. I am going to slowly take a look at your code and see if I have any more questions.

Comment: For some reason when I run your code (I copy and pasted it), I'm getting the following error:
 File "C:\Python27\Dataframetesting2.py", line 18, in <module>
    14          Brian    Tiffany """)
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: Thanks! (It seems it's not good form to say "thanks" on this site? but I appreciate you following through, so it feels rude to not even say "thank you")

Answer (score 2):

IIUC (it's hard as you didn't post expected/desired DF) you can do it this way:

```
df = (pd.read_html("file:///C:/Python27/babyname999.html")[0]
        .rename(columns = {'0': 'Rank', '1': 'Boys', '2': 'Females'})
        .drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)
        .set_index('Rank')
)
```

then:

```
In [86]: df['Rank_Boys'], df['Rank_Females'] = df.sort_values('Boys').index, df.sort_values('Females').index

In [87]: df
Out[87]:
           Boys    Females  Rank_Boys  Rank_Females
1       Michael   Jennifer         14             3
2   Christopher    Jessica          2             6
3       Matthew     Amanda         10             9
4         Jason      Sarah          5            10
5         David    Melissa          7             1
6        Joshua        Amy          4             2
7         James     Nicole          8            13
8          John  Stephanie         11             5
9        Robert  Elizabeth          6            11
10       Daniel    Heather         12             7
11       Joseph   Michelle          3            12
12       Justin    Rebecca          1             4
13         Ryan   Kimberly          9             8
14        Brian    Tiffany         13            14
```

Comment: Wow, you made the first part of the code so efficient.

df = (pd.read_html("file:///C:/Python27/babyname999.html")[0]
        .rename(columns = {'0': 'Rank', '1': 'Boys', '2': 'Females'})
        .drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)
        .set_index('Rank')
)


I noticed that you you used "drop" instead of "del" when removing a column. Any difference I should be aware of? I don't understand what the second parameter 1 does in drop.

 .drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)

Thanks!